# For approximation f within $0.0001$ of $\int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{x} dx$ using Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, riemann-sum

From the formula on Wikipedia, $\frac{M\left(b-a\right)^2}{2n} =  \frac{1}{2 \cdot n} < 0.0001$ and my simplification is due to $M$ being the maximum of the absolute value of the first derivative on the interval (so $\left| - \frac{1}{x^2} \right|$ when $1 \leq x \leq 2$. And, $b-a=2-1=1$

But then I get an "unusually" large number when I solve for $n$. It seems that $ n = 5001$ is the minimum amount since I'd need $n$ to be greater than $5000$. The reason I say unsual is because the trapezoidal, midpoint, and Simpson's are so much smaller that I feel some sort of calculation error. For those, I got $41$, $29$ and $8$

Like I know that the other methods were better but I didn't realize it was soo much better than Riemann sums. (But I can see how Riemann sums aren't to good since their error estimates don't have $n$ to the power of anything, and so you'd need a large $n$ in order to make up for no exponents.)

My question: **is n=5001 correct?**

Comment: It is unclear what your question is.

Comment: Basically, is $n=5001$ correct for a left or right Riemann sum to be within 0.0001

Comment: The right Riemann sum will be better than the left Riemann sum because the function $1/x$ is convex and decreasing. Not much better, though.

Comment: A computer program gives $0.0001$ precision for the right Riemann sum at $n=2500.$

Comment: Fascinatingly, the left sum gets $0.0001$ precision at $n=2501.$ Certainly proving my point about the right only being slightly better.

Comment: Not sure why my numbers are twice as big as yours since maybe I've defined "within 0.0001" differently? But wouldn't I have the left side of the inequaltiy be 0.0001

I'm looking at other example questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432546/finding-n-value-for-trapezoid-and-midpoint-rule-errors

Comment: Well, the error between the right sum and the integral is less than half the maximum error. The maximum error would be when the left value is "mostly right" on every interval in the partition/